# Windows Media Player 11 fails to authenticate with proxy (ISA)

Tags: proxy, windows-media-player

We have some users who need to use a 3rd party site that embeds Windows Media Player streaming video into a web page.  Our users go through an ISA proxy server to connect to the Internet.  The browser has no problems accessing the site through the proxy.
When Media Player loads, we get prompted for network credentials, but the authentication fails.
If we set up Internet Explorer 8 to not use the proxy, Media Player has no problem.

Media Player is configured to use the RTSP/TCP and HTTP protocols, but not the RTSP/UDP protocol.  Is this necessary?  Is there a registry key I can use to enable it?

Is this more of a proxy server issue?  The proxy guy says it's a desktop issue.

Comment: Starting a bounty on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I had to call Microsoft on this one.
The problem is that Media Player can't handle using a fully qualified domain name for the proxy server address.  We had WMP configured to use the browser settings, which was an FQDN url to an auto config script.

After changing WMP to do a direct connection to the proxy server using a NETBIOS name instead of FQDN, it stopped prompting for credentials.

Although it's a fix, it's more of a bug to me.  WMP should handle FQDN for proxies.

Comment: I'm taking my bounty back too.  :)

Comment: Too late. From [Bounty FAQ](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) : "The non-refundable amount of the bounty is immediately deducted from your reputation".